# jQuery UI Snap to Element then Resize to fit container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

https://jsfiddle.net/tk48ecxb/24/

Here is an example of the code I'm working with. It works fairly well with larger sizes but it breaks the small size boxes. Not sure why its moving them when removing resized boxes, that isn't happening in the actual project I'm working on. Need the boxes, which are actually svg's in the project, to fill the width of the larger boxes and not really be choppy or attach in weird ways.

Also, anyway to trigger an event when all boxes are filled?

HTML

```
<div class="top-row">
<ul class="holderList">
    <li class="holder" id="large"></li>
    <li class="holder" id="medium"></li>
    <li class="holder" id="small"></li>
    <li class="holder" id="tiny"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="bottom-row">
  <ul>
    <li class="square" id="square1">
</li>
    <li class="square" id="square2"></li>
    <li class="square" id="square3"></li>
    <li class="square" id="square4"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul li{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
}
.holderList > li{
 margin: 20px;
}

#large{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

}
#medium{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;

}
#small{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

}
#tiny{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

}

.square{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

JS

```
$(".square").draggable({
 drag: function(event, ui) {
     var draggable = $(this).data("ui-draggable");
     $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
         ui = $.extend({}, ui, {
             snapElement: $(element.item),
             snapping: element.snapping
         });
         if (element.snapping) {
             if (!element.snappingKnown) {
                 element.snappingKnown = true;
                 draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
             }
         } else if (element.snappingKnown) {
             element.snappingKnown = false;
             draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
         }
     });
 },
 snap: ".holder",
 snapMode: "inner",
 snapped: function(event, ui) {
     var squareWidth = ui.snapElement.width();
     var squareHeight = ui.snapElement.height();


     ui.helper.css({width: squareWidth, height: squareHeight});



 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

All I need to do was add snapTolerance apparently.

Now to figure out how to create a popup if all windows are filled.